# How to clear the entered data in the form once I click submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

Below is the code I have written so far. How can I clear the data in form input box once I click on Add Course? I have tried setCourse({id:"", title:"", description:""}) inside handleForm at the end but it does not work.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Button, Container, Form, FormGroup, Input } from "reactstrap";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import base_url from "../api/bootapi";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';

const AddCourse = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = "Add Course" //adding webpage title
    }, []);// with this blank arry the function works first time when component mount not when update

    const [course, setCourse] = useState({});

    //form handler function
    const handleForm = (e) => {
        console.log(course);
        postDataToServer(course);
        e.preventDefault();

    }

    //creating function to post data on server
    const postDataToServer = (data) => {
        axios.post(`${base_url}/api/v1/courses`, data).then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                toast.success("Courses has been added.", {
                    position: "bottom-center"
                })
            },
            (error) => {
                //for error
                console.log(error);
                toast.error("Something went wrong.", {
                    position: "bottom-center"
                })
            }
        );
    }
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className="text-center my-3">Fill Course Detail</h1>
            <Form onSubmit={handleForm}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <label for="userId">Course Id</label>
                    <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter CourseId Here" name="userId" id="userId"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setCourse({ ...course, id: e.target.value });
                        }} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <label for="title">Course Title</label>
                    <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title Here" name="title" id="title"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setCourse({ ...course, title: e.target.value });
                        }} />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <label for="description">Course Description</label>
                    <Input type="textarea" placeholder="Enter description Here" name="description" id="description" style={{ height: 150 }}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setCourse({ ...course, description: e.target.value });
                        }} />
                </FormGroup>

                <Container className="text-center">
                    <Button type="submit" color="success">Add Course</Button>
                    <Button type="reset" color="warning" style={{ marginLeft: '8px' }}>Clear</Button>
                </Container>


            </Form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default AddCourse;
```

I have tried setCourse({id:"", title:"", description:""}) inside handleForm at the end but it does not work.

Comment: You need to make your inputs _controlled_ by using `value={course.someProperty}`

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the general method for clearing the information in all user interface elements:

> Moralis.UI.clear();

If you wish to clear just some certain elements you can use **setAttribute** at each of them.

> var inputBox = document.getElementById ("myInputBox");
> inputBox.setAttribute("value", "");